# Maxed-out Hausdorff metric

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $(Y,d)$ be a non-degenerate compact metric space, and let $d_H$ be the Hausdorff metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) on $K(Y)$ generated by $d$.

Here $K(Y)$ is the set of non-empty compact subsets of $Y$.

Let $M$ be the maximum value of $d_H$.

If $A\in K(Y)$, and $d_H(A,Y)=M$, then is $A$ necessarily nowhere dense in $Y$?.

Comment: No. $Y=\{ y\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I assume >1 point (edited)

Comment: Then another counterexample is $Y=\{ x,y \}$.

Comment: I think the statement in the question is true if $d:Y\times Y \to [0, s[$ is surjective where $s = \sup\{d(x,y): x,y\in Y\}$. I am trying to prove this.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: A counterexample -- take two copies of (the usual metric on) $[0,1]$, and declare two points in different copies to be distance $1$ apart. Taking $A$ to be one of the two copies maximizes $d_H(A,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If start with a maximizing set $A$ in $Y$, and then consider $(\{0\} \times A) \cup (\{1\} \times Y)$ in $\mathbf{2} \times Y$, we see that it is maximizing again. Here we need to use a reasonable metric $d'$ on $\mathbf{2} \times Y$, eg $d'((i,x),(i,y)) = d(x,y)$ and $d'((i,x),(j,y)) = M$ for $i \neq j$.

Thus, being maximal is a local property (for a sufficiently large notion of local), and cannot imply a global property such as nowhere dense.

[While writing this, Will Brian posted essentially the same idea in the comments.]